How to configure a Spring Boot WebTestClient in a Servlet application to work with OAuth 2.0 Login
I have a bunch of end-to-end tests that use WebTestClient in a Servlet Spring Boot application.
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class End2EndTest {
    
    @Autowired
    protected WebTestClient webClient;

    public void test() {
        webClient
            .get()
            .uri("api/v1/tasks")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk();
    
    }
}

I have now added security using Spring Security OAuth 2 login feature:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurer {
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       // ...

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(c -> c
            .requestMatchers(GET, URL_V1_API_DOCS + "/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(URL_V1_BASE + "/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().denyAll());

       http           
           .oauth2Login(withDefaults());
           // ...

        return http.build();
    }
}

The application runs fine and I can log in using a Keycloak auth server configured in application.properties.
For my tests what I would like is to configure WebTestClient to login in a Keycloak test container.
Or at least know how to mock it*. I see support for mockOidcLogin when using a WebTestClient in a reactive application or MockMvc in a servlet application. Still, it doesn't seem possible to mock it when using WebTestClient for a servlet application (Spring Security throws runtime errors).
*(Independently whether using mocks in an end-to-end test is the right thing to do).


I don't mind if it is either using a mocked user or with a real login using a Keycloak test container.

Actually, you should mind:

with a mocked identity, you want to skip the part of the filter chain which builds the Authentication instance (from the session cookie and data saved in session in the case of a client with oauth2Login, or from a Bearer token in a resource server). There are some MockMvc request post-processors and WebTestClient mutators designed to build Authentication instances of various types and to populate the test security context with it
with a test container, the test runs with a "real" identity: fetched from an authorization server instance, and then parsed, validated, and turned into an Authentication instance by the security filter-chain (not crafted by the test framework). In the case of authorization-code flow like you're using, this will require automating a user login form filling (like what you do with Protractor and alike in end-to-end testing)


I see support for mockOidcLogin when using a WebTestClient in a reactive application or MockMvc in a servlet application

That's because it's much more natural to use a synchronized tool when testing a synchronized app and a reactive tool when testing a reactive one. Not to mention that using WebTestClient will require adding spring-webflux to the classpath (which should not be necessary in a servlet application)...
You can @AutoConfigureMockMvc in a @SpringBootTest of a servlet application. Similarly, you can @AutoConfigureWebTestClient in a @SpringBootTest, but only in WebFlux applications.
Something working in your case
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Import(SecurityConfigurer.class)
class ServletClientApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void givenRequestIsNotAuthorized_whenGetDocsIndex_thenIsOk() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/v1/docs/index.html")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    void givenUserIsAnonymous_whenGetProfile_thenIsRedirected() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/profile.html").with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.anonymous())).andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection());
    }

    @Test
    void givenUserIsAuthenticated_whenGetProfile_thenIsOk() throws Exception {
        mockMvc
            .perform(get("/profile.html").with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.oauth2Login().authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("NICE"))))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}

spring-addons-oauth2-test
This is a lib I wrote in addition to OAuth2 post-processors & mutators in spring-security-test, to provide test annotations to populate the security context of both WebMvc and WebFlux apps:
@Test
@WithOidcLogin("NICE")
void givenUserIsNice_whenGetProfile_thenIsOk() throws Exception {
  ...
}


Thanks, but I already had tons of end to end tests using WebTestClient before I added OAuth2 login, as it is a valid way to do it even for servlet applications (docs) . I would prefer no to have to migrate all my tests.

If your tests are "end to end", then you should have the all infrastructure up, which, in case of OAuth2 security, includes an authorization server. Your test should get "real" tokens from the authorization server before sending a request to a resource server. spring-security-test is not adapted for such scenarios, and JUnit is probably not the best end-to-end test framework.

Unit testing an application with "end to end" tests is slow, complicated, and hard to maintain. With spring-security-test, you can write unit tests (just one class with mocked dependencies: WebMvcTest or WebFluxTest in the case of controllers) and integration tests (Spring beans injected from the test application context: SpringBootTest). For about the same reasons you should not unit test an application with integration tests. Now if you don't want to go the recommended way, it could work, but be prepared to waste "tons" of time and effort (a lot of "tons").

I am not unit testing my application with end-to-end test. They are just one layer of all my tests. I have unit tests >>> integration tests >> and end-to-end tests. For end-to-end I agree that I should have all the infrastructure up, that is why I use test containers (S3, Keycloak, etc.). But for OAuth2 login I haven't managed to make it work with Keycloak container, that is why I was asking for help. I also use Spring security for authorization server and it is pretty easy to integrate with a Keycloak container in my tests. Thanks.

I edited my question to make it clear that I want to integrate it with a Keycloak container.

So this is not unit tests any more? You wrote earlier that you have "tons" of this tests. If this really are end-to-end tests, you shouldn't have that many to migrate to another client. Also oauth2Login means that you have a UI and user interaction in a browser during authentication. How do you intend to achieve that with JUnit (fill login forms, possibly with Multi-Factor Auth, and click a login button) ? As I wrote earlier spring-security-test is of help to put a mocked authentication in the security context, not to mimic user  interaction with a real authorization server.

I think I never said they were unit tests. And yes, I may have many of these tests or only just one, that is not the point of the question. Yes, I have UI, user interaction... I agreed that it is not simple to achieve that with JUnit, but that is why I am asking to the community.
